# Java HikariCP classes

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm currently making a server in Java, as database stuff I'm using HikariCP (because AFAIK, it's the best library). I try to do it as good as possible so I hope some of you can review my classes.

First, the DatabaseManager.java class:

```java
package PKG.storage;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class DatabaseManager {

    private final HikariDataSource _dataSource;

    public DatabaseManager(String hostname, String username, String password, String database) {
        HikariConfig databaseConfiguration = new HikariConfig();
        databaseConfiguration.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        databaseConfiguration.setInitializationFailFast(true);
        databaseConfiguration.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":3306/" + database);
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", hostname);
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("port", "3306");
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", database);
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.logger", "com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger");
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.logSlowQueries", "true");
        databaseConfiguration.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.dumpQueriesOnException", "true");
        databaseConfiguration.setAutoCommit(true);
        databaseConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(3400L);
        databaseConfiguration.setValidationTimeout(3399L);
        databaseConfiguration.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000L);
        databaseConfiguration.setMaxLifetime(2874000L);
        databaseConfiguration.setIdleTimeout(2874000L);
        _dataSource = new HikariDataSource(databaseConfiguration);
    }

    public DatabaseQuery create() {     
        try {
            return new DatabaseQuery(_dataSource.getConnection());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my DatabaseQuery.java file:

```java
package PKG.storage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DatabaseQuery implements AutoCloseable {

    private Connection _connection;
    private PreparedStatement _stmt;

    public DatabaseQuery(Connection connection) {
        try {
            _connection = connection;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //...
        }
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        try {
            _stmt = _connection.prepareStatement(query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //...
        }
    }

    public void setInt(int index, int i) {
        try {
            _stmt.setInt(index, i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public void setString(int index, String i) {
        try {
            _stmt.setString(index, i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public void setBoolean(int index, boolean i) {
        try {
            _stmt.setBoolean(index, i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public void setDate(int index, Date i) {
        try {
            _stmt.setDate(index, i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public void setDouble(int index, double i) {
        try {
            _stmt.setDouble(index, i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public void execute() {
        try {
            _stmt.execute();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public int insert() {
        try {
            if (_stmt.execute()) {
                return _stmt.getGeneratedKeys().getInt(1);
            }

            return -1;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        try {
            return _stmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getString() {
        try {
            ResultSet set = getResultSet();

            if (set != null && set.next()) {
                return set.getString(0);
            }

            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getInt() {
        try {
            ResultSet set = getResultSet();

            if (set != null && set.next()) {
                return set.getInt(1);
            }

            return -1;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        _stmt.close();
        _connection.close();
    }
}
```

I know I got a lot of bad Exception handling (like not showing the error in debug mode), but that will be added later. I'd like to get some review especially on the DatabaseQuery class.

Comment: The `//...` parts, is that how the actual code looks, or did you remove what was there before posting it here?

Comment: It will be replaced by either a writing to the file or a line print or both. Not sure yet. I will change it soon.

Comment: Agreed, HikariCP seems to be the best connection pooling. Moreover, unlike others it worked for me without problem. But that's all I can agree with. Some long long time ago, I wrote something similar to what you did (my motivation was that working with plain SQL was a pain) ... and it was no good.

Comment: In general, you should change the code after posting it for review. However, here it IMHO doesn't matter as *anything* you fill in is wrong (see my review).

Answer (score 2):

You code consists mainly of exception swallowing. Saying that "handling ... will be added later" is no excuse. If you think that *not throwing is good*, then why do all libraries throw?

Ditch it. Never return -1 in case of an exception. Returning -1 is ambiguous and there's no guarantee that anyone ever checks it. It's only acceptable with things like `InputStream#read` where it's performance-critical and clearly distinct from all normal return values. When there's already an exception, then its performance cost has already been paid, so stick with it.

> It will be replaced by either a writing to the file or a line print or both.

Using a proper [logger](https://www.slf4j.org) would be much better... but still plain wrong. What you're writing is a sort of library code as it should be used from many places which you don't know yet. In some of the places, `-1` or `null` will be a valid return value and then you have a problem. Anyway, you'll have a problem when debugging as your code won't work (maybe because of a forgotten "exceptional return value" check) and you'll have to look the problem up in some logfiles.

*If this was a good idea, `java.util.sql` would write some funny messages into some funny files instead of throwing.*

Most of the time, the right exception handling is no handling. Just let it bubble up. Declare the exception and you're done. Somewhere near the main method, you'll know what to do. Then you'll catch it and do some meaningful action, like log the exception, say sorry to the user, retry or terminate.

If you dislike your code infested with throws clauses, than wrap the exception in some `YourRuntimeSqlException`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `HikariCP`, but I'll try to do this as good as I can.

## `Exception` overload

You use a massive amount of

```
try{
  //Code
}catch(Exception e){
  //Exception handling
}
```

blocks. To catch all `Exception`'s isn't a good practice. You should use more specified classes. As I said I don't know anything about `HikariCP`. Maybe they use `throws Exception`, what would be at least equally bad practice.

## `Autocloseable`

Implementing `Autocloseable` is a good idea, but [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) implements `Autocloseable` and is more common. `Autocloseable` should only be used if you have an other closing method (like `flush()`) and want to use this class in `try` statements and use the `close` method to redirect.
=> Implement `Closeable` instead of `Autocloseable`

## All your `get`'s

What if I get a `-1` as regular result? Your code will return that `-1` and therefore produce the same output if there was an error.

```
int res = query.getInt();
if(res == -1){
  System.err.println("Database returned Error");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

This `if` statement is for error handling. Since there is an built-in error management and there is already an error thrown this isn't even an performance advantage. And just leads to confusion.

Also what if I didn't even executed the query? It returns the default value. In this case it would be a performance advantage to add an `private boolean`, set him to `true` if the query is executed and add

```
if(!isExexuted){
  return -1;
}
```

to the `get...` methods. Also I would recommend to add the possibility to change error/default values.

<s>I didn't know, but most Java is zero-indexed, so I think this is too. So change the `set.getInt(1);` to `set.getInt(0);`</s> It is 1indexed. But you can still add an counter and increment it.

```
int index = <s>0</s>1;

public int getInt(int default_){
  if(!isExecuted){
    return default_;
  }
  return getResultSet().getInt();
}
```

Comment: Nah, in ResultSet it's not zero indexed. I thought that the first time but indexes actually start with 1. I'll change the Exception into specific exception types which - I agree - is better. For the -1 stuff, the getInt() isn't used that much, and in cases it IS used, it can't return -1 (lets say, get ID by name/email, ID can't be -1). About the Autocloseable and Closeable I didn't know. I'll go and read about those. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: In this case I'll edit this

Comment: `public int getInt(index++)` won't compile. Converting the `ResultSet` to a list (or iterating the `ResulSet` as is) is the only sane option if you want index it.

Comment: I don't know what i was thinking while writing this... I'm sorry